# parse long from exponential number in firestore security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i m allowing users to push values like => 1.581652625083E12

now how do i parse a long number out of it in firestore security rules ?

i want to know it the value is in some range

it might look like timestamp but its not

i have tried looking everythin in the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Integer) but doesn't find anything useful

there is float parsing reference

```
float("2.2") == 2.2
float(2) == 2.0
```

there is int parsing possible

```
int("2") == 2
int(2.0) == 2
```

so is there a method to parse long like that ?

puff and team please help

Answer (score 1):

If you allow users to write numbers of any sort in Firestore, they should be represented as number type fields.  This means you should not allow strings that are formatted like exponential numbers.  There are no methods to parse strings of arbitrary string formats - the client should parse and convert those into actual number values.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) states that Firestore is limited to 64-bit floating point numbers.  If you are using anything larger than that, Firestore number fields will not work well for you.

Comment: thanx doug ! i appriciate that.

Comment: all i want to say is firestore security rules are not good for checking "write" operations. for a small project with 5 nodes i have more than 500 lines of security rules. mostly because of data validataion. i m switching to APIs. even when i have tested all the possible cases using emulator. something always fails. it sucks